# Laravel return duplicate records where all data is the same

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I'm wondering if its possible to get a list of all records that are exactly the same (every columns data is matched, except for the ID).

At the moment, i am returning a list of all records which are duplicates based on one column, this works good, but some of them have different data in other columns and i need to filter those ones out.

This is what I have at the moment;

```php
$dupes = \DB::table('customers')
  ->select('phone', \DB::raw('COUNT("phone") as `count`'))
  ->groupBy('phone')
  ->having('count', '>', 1)
  ->get();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello you just need to add all the columns in select and group by

```
\DB::table('customers')
 ->select(['phone', 'column_name', 'column_name_2'])
 ->groupBy(['phone', 'column_name', 'column_name_2'])
 ->havingRaw('COUNT(id) > 1')
 ->get()
```

Like this you will get duplicated rows